# [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement. JSP

Tags: java, sql-server, jsp

After running the below code I have been getting this error . this code runs perfectly when I don't specify the column name after "Fitness", else it gives error as:

> [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.

JSP:

```
<%@page import="java.sql.*"%>
    <%try {
        Connection hi = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:hilal");
        Statement st = hi.createStatement();
        st.executeUpdate("Insert into Fit(UserId,Count,Date,e_id) values(46,5,160218,'e1') ");
        response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
%>
```

Comment: You really should avoid using reserved words as names. You will have to wrap these in []. So it would be [Count], [Date] etc. Save yourself the hassle and use a more descriptive name. Date and count are really too ambiguous to be good names anyway. What date is it? Count of what?

Comment: Thank You Very Much  PeterSmith

Comment: Sean Lange Thank You Very Much